# Connectivity issue on c3p0 after restarting server

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, c3p0

I am using c3p0 for Hibernate connectivity to Oracle database in my application. We have two servers running in parallel. Normally works Ok but after restart one of the servers getting exception when trying to connect to DB through c3p0. The root exception being thrown is

```
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 53 more
```

After another restart, the server behaves correctly. I am using hibernate-c3p0-4.3.6.Final.

Here is my c3p0 connectivity config

```
<bean id="dataSource"
class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"
<property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
<property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}" />
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="2"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxStatements" value="200"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="300"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement"  value="10"/>
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="90"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="120"/>
</bean>
```

Has anybody experienced similar behavior?

Comment: Can you post the properties file for used to assign properties to hibernate..?? where you have jdbc.url.. And also what driver are you using??

Comment: That does sound like a max connection limit is set in Oracle and it's been breached so nobody gets any new connection

Answer (score 0):

Is this reproducible? If not I guess it is one of two problems:

1. Either there actually was a problem with creating connections to the database. If I remember correctly with Oracle it is rather easy possible that existing connections work just fine, but new ones can't get created, for example when the listener service become unavailable.
2. Or some process(es) during startup used up all the connections available. This can happen for example when process get started by some kind of queue and due to the down time that queue is rather full. Note that the connection limit might be the one configured in the connection pool or the one configured in the oracle database.